# Synchronize files with remote server

Tags: c#, jsp, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have written a program to synchronize files with a remote server. But I'm unable to find a method to pass the username & password of the server. I have provided the coding below. It works between two local directories. I have used microsoft sync framework here. But i'm unable to modify it to be used with the remote server even after searching a solution for days. Can somebody please let me know a way to include the credentials here. thanks in advance

```
string RemoteserverPath = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com/login/login.jsp";
        string ClientPath = "E:/test";

        try
        {
            FileSyncOptions options = FileSyncOptions.ExplicitDetectChanges |
                     FileSyncOptions.RecycleDeletedFiles | FileSyncOptions.RecyclePreviousFileOnUpdates | FileSyncOptions.RecycleConflictLoserFiles;

            FileSyncScopeFilter filter = new FileSyncScopeFilter();
            filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.lnk"); // Exclude all *.lnk files

            DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica(
                RemoteserverPath, filter, options);
            DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica(
                ClientPath, filter, options);

            // Sync in both directions
            SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(RemoteserverPath, ClientPath, null, options);
            SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(ClientPath, RemoteserverPath, null, options);
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("\nException from File Sync Provider:\n" + e1.ToString());                
        }
```

Comment: You could try to specify credentials in the URL string, if supported by the server.

Comment: Do you really want to send files to a login page, or am I misunderstanding your code?

Comment: @AgentFire, Hi I changed my coding as below. But it throws an error message called, "Identifier expected". string replica1RootPath = "https://data-set1.xxx.xxx.xxxxx.com","xxx","xxxx";

Answer (score 0):

You could not use Microsoft Sync Framework to Sync ftp(remote) files like this. You must use Proxy provider (like WCF) to synchronize with Microsoft Sync Framework

Comment: can you provide examples how to create Proxy provider or any good links

Comment: I am sory but I have no example. I think it is hard to code, so I code mine without Microsoft Sync Framework, I wrote file information on database, then synchronized them with my code on FTP.

Answer (score -1):

as [hubeybozkul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26834388/4251431) described in his answer we must have `proxy` or `web service` responsible for transfer the date and other operations that sync framework need it

after long searching I just found these `porjects` that did it

1. [Sync101 with Remote Change Application over WCF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sync101-with-Remote-Change-e1877a3a) from [msdn code gallery](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/)
2. [Remote file synchronization over wcf using sync framework 2.1](https://github.com/labrinth1/RemoteSync) from github